what is the definition of $e^z$ in 4.7 Trigonometric functions, Terence Tao's Analysis 2
In Terence Tao's "Analysis 2", Section 4.6 "A digression on complex numbers" meticulously defines
$$\exp(z):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$$ for a complex $z$. However, in the subsequent Section 4.7 "Trigonometric functions", the notation $e^z$ is introduced and utilized without explicit definition. This progression raises a few questions:
Does the usage of $e^z$ immediately after the definition of (exp(z)) imply an implicit assumption by Tao that the two are equivalent when dealing with complex numbers? If so, is this equivalence a commonly accepted convention in the literature of mathematics, particularly in complex analysis?
How is the transition from (exp(z)) to $e^z$ typically justified within the mathematical framework?  For students or readers new to complex analysis, what is the recommended approach to bridge the understanding from the well-defined (exp(z)) to the direct application of $e^z$, particularly when navigating literature where these notations seem interchangeable?

Also posted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/470372/116247

Sorry, I just want to get the answer as soon as possible

Hi! This question seems more appropriate here than on MO. I appreciate the ardent desire to understand this more completely, but the sense of urgency should be tempered by a consideration for spam avoidance. I recommend that the question be removed from MO.

Also, I recommend that MathJax be used more completely throughout your question, especially as it is drawing a fine distinction between alternative notations. Someone might be left wondering whether you mean to distinguish between $e^x$ and e^x.

$\exp(z)$ is just another notation for $e^z$. It's useful to improve readability when $z$ is a longer expression like $-\frac{1}{2}x^T\Sigma^{-1}x$.

@BrianTung I apologize again for my reckless behavior. And I don't know how to delete the question, as I submitted it while browsing as a guest. Could you help me for deleting the question?

@user1317952: I wouldn't say it was reckless haha. Your enthusiasm is commendable. But now that you know about the policy on multiple posting, it's preferable to avoid it unless and until your first-choice venue doesn't produce results.

@BrianTung Yes! I won't make this mistake a second time.

Clearly, in section 4.7, Tao uses the notation $e^z$ for the $\exp(z)$ defined in section 4.6, since he writes (for a complex number $z$):
From the power series definition of $\exp$, we have
$$e^{iz}=1+iz-\frac{z^2}{2!}-\frac{iz^3}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}+\dots$$
In this context, the two notations $\exp(z)$ and $e^z$ are widely used as equivalent.

So, for every complex number x, we have $exp(x) = e^x$. This doesn't require any proof because that's how we define $e^z$.

Indeed, this is how He defines it.

And thank you very much! This has puzzled me for a long time. I initially studied Tao's Analysis precisely to obtain a clear definition of $e^z$. Therefore, when I saw Tao directly using $e^z$ without explicitly defining it, I was quite disappointed.

Based on the description here, I tried defining $x^y$ as $\exp(y\ln x)$, where (x) is a real number and (y) is a complex number; from this, it can be conveniently deduced that $e^{az} = (e^a)^z, (e^a)^z = \exp(z\ln e^a) = \exp(za) = \exp(az)= e^{az}.$ Furthermore, $x^{y+z} = x^y + x^z$. I would like to confirm if this definition of $x^y$ is correct or if it's just wishful thinking on my part?

@ZhanYi for positive real $x$, yes

For real numbers the exponential function $\exp(x)$ is the same as the exponentiation $e^x$. That is
$$\exp(x) = \lim_{\frac{p}{q} \rightarrow x} e^{\frac{p}{q}}$$
where $x\in \mathbb{R}, p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$. For complex exponents however the RHS is not usable because it requires the definition of $e^i$. However one can prove that $\exp(z)$ is the unique analytic continuation of $e^x$ on $\mathbb{C}$. $\exp(z)$'s infinite series definition is also equivalent to each following statement:

$\dfrac{d\exp(z)}{dz} = \exp(z)$ and $\exp(0) = 1$
$\exp(z) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\dfrac{z}{n}\right)^n$

thus $\exp(z)$ is used as the definition of $e^z$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$
